# The limitations and issues for Firebase support Unity standalone

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine

I've read the official Firebase documentation about limitations for standalone applications. The picture below shows the current limitations. I typically use Firebase for my Android and iOS projects, but now I want to build a project for Steam (using Unity standalone). I'm confused because the documentation says that Firebase support for desktop is beta and not recommended for release projects (only for workflow), but the limitation table only mentions that it doesn't support A/B testing, analytics, app distribution (which I'm not sure what it is), cloud messaging, and crashlytics. These all seem acceptable for my Steam project. Does it mean that I can still use Firebase for my new standalone project? Do I need to be concerned about anything? Or is there any reason I shouldn't use Firebase?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The [Firebase Unity SDK git repo](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-unity-sdk/blob/main/docs/readme.md#desktop-workflow-implementations) has more information.

Some of the products that work in the editor and standalone builds do not have all of their functionality.

Additionally, on the page it reads "**This is a Beta feature,**" and as such, there are no guarantees of parity with the mobile offerings or for long term support of a given feature set.